# Is there a German-English dictionary in PDF (or that works offline)?

Tags: resource, dictionary, english

Does any of these famous ([dict](http://dict.cc), [leo](http://dict.leo.org), [dix](http://dix.osola.com), [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org), etc.) online dictionaries have a free `pdf` dictionary? (I guess the answer is *no*, because less people would then visit the page again, but who knows?) From any other source?  Or is there an app that serves as a German-English dictionary, which can be used offline?

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I am not always able to be online and I really need an offline, PDF-converted English-German dictionary or anything that loads onto a portable device.

Comment: For advanced users such as yourself, printed dictionaries are still the best. And they're always offline; hence portable, if you don't mind carrying along a 3 kg brick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [download section of dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=about:wordlist), you can download offline dictionaries.

I have not tried this with Windows or Linux, but on a Mac, you can download the dictionary for Mac OS X 10.6 (works on 10.7 and 10.8 too). Once you download the file [linked here for convenience](http://www1.dict.cc/download/macosx10.6_dict.cc_dictionary.pkg), you have two choices:

1. You could just double click the package installer and let it do it’s thing.
2. You could manually install the dictionary file by first extracting it from the .pkg file and following my instructions below.

Put the extracted file in this folder (the package installer does this for you):

> ~/Library/Dictionaries

To get there, you could click finder>Go To> type in the path and press enter. Paste dict.cc file in there.

You should be able to start your build-in dictionary program and go to the preferences, search the list and check the dictionary to enable it. You can also optionally drag the dictionary up the list to give it higher priority if you plan on using it frequently.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's a piece of software for Android that lets you download and view the English wiktionary offline.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wikokit.kiwidict.enwikt

I had to download the dictionary file separately to get it to work (see description in marketplace).

And Personally, I don't think pdf style dictionaries would be very user-friendly, especially not on a mobile device.

You might also want to consider investing into a specialized electronic (handheld) dictionary, which give you access to professionally edited dictionaries, which are still better in my opinion. (at least for Japanese-English)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any published German-English dictionaries off the top of my head, but http://dict.cc/ has a mobile app for iOS that allows you to download its database for offline use, provides you have an iOS-powered device:

Paid dict app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dict.cc+-dictionary/id521791825?mt=8

Free dict app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dict.cc-dictionary/id327732352?mt=8

You can usually find published books/dictionaries online in PDF format for free, but that would be "stealing," so I can't recommend that or provide help with that.

Comment: There is an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.dict.dictcc&hl=en) as well ;) Completely free.

Answer (score 1):

At freshmeat, there is the OpenSource program [Steak/Xsteak](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xsteak) for offline use.

Comment: Gut! Schade nur, dass ich kein Unix-kompatibles tragbares Gerät habe.

Comment: Why answered in German?

Comment: GTK+ ist auch für Windows verfügbar, soweit ich informiert bin. Und eine unix-kompatible Shell gibt es ebenso - Gnu-utils am gleichen Ort, soweit ich mich erinnere. Hauptsache ist aber doch ohnehin das Wörterbuch das man sicher vom Listenformat in ein PDF umwandeln kann.