# Resources for learning German

Tags: resource

Since they have same questions on different language learning SE websites([resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)), I'd like to write one for German language since it's a great idea to have all kinds of resources in one place.

This is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning German and it has been approved by the Community itself.

It should be clear that **the resources are not written by one user or only by the mods, but *by whoever wants to contribute***.

Just write in the appropriate answer/section. If you have concerns, questions, [post a meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/), so we don't clutter the comments, but you can link your meta question from the comments.

Questions regarding such resources **are not allowed anymore**, except for very specific and on topic requests (ask on [Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're unsure about your question). Follow the instructions made in the question about how to post, what can be posted, etc.

#### Organization

- Answers have a type of resource **each**.
- If possible, state whether the material is directed towards a **beginner**, **intermediate** or an **advanced** audience.
- **Do not** include links that lead to illegal content or sites that host such content. If you see any, please **flag for moderator attention** and choose "other" so you can point us to the content. We'll delete it as soon as we see the flag.
- Both free and commercial resources are allowed, but make sure to include a note if they are. Remember the [rules about self-promotion](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). Include also if registration is required.
- Include links to the sites only, *don't post images*, they would take too much space.
- Add the resources in alphabetical order so they're easier to find. :)

*Note: new rules could be added in the future.*

#### Alphabetical Index

- [Audio Resources](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9532/23): Audio files where you hear a voice talking or reading.
- [Books](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9536/23): Books from German authors or translations.
- [Dictionaries](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/23): Stand-alone or dictionary files for you to use on your computer.
- [Newspapers](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9561/23): Famous or not services that provide news for Germany and the rest of the world... in German.
- [Online courses](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9534/23): Free or paid services online that teach you the language through lessons.
- [Podcasts](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15316/9183): Audio files that feature people speaking about the language or giving tips/lessons to learners.
- [Software](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9531/23): This can be any software ranging from plugins for the browser over mobile apps up to standalone applications for the computer.
- [Television](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8655/): TV channels, shows in German.
- [Textbooks](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24955): Grammar books that teach you the grammar of the language with theory and exercises.
- [Video Resources](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15315/9183): Video resources which help learning German and are not TV stations
- [Websites](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9560/23): Sites that give help for learning German. They give material, tips, hints, and various help for self-learners or regular students.

Comment: In case an entry is missing where you want to add a resource please ask us to generate it for you. You can do so in [meta], ask us in [chat] or by flagging this post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 20):

### German TV-Stations

[**ARD**](http://www.ardmediathek.de)
Choose *Fernsehen* and then *Sendungen A-Z* for a complete list.
Mostly News and Edutainment, it seems. Use [this site](https://programm.ard.de/TV/TV-mit-Originalversion/Startseite) to get a list with shows not original German, which are provided with "OT" (from "Original Ton", original language) too and information how to receive the OT-version.

[**ZDF**](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek)
Again, choose *Sendungen A-Z* for a complete list.
A quick scan revealed only "Inspektor Barnaby" as non-German series, lots of news, cooking and quiz shows

[**DW**](https://www.dw.com/en/top-stories/s-9097)
Aims "not-German" people living in and outside Germany. News from Germany in German and multiple other languages. A lots of resources designed to learn German (as I can see mostly free).

[**Sat1**](http://www.sat1.de/video)
Navy CIS, Hannibal, Elementary, Criminal Minds, The Mentalist, ...

[**RTL**](http://rtl-now.rtl.de)
CSI, House MD (Dr. House), The Following, The Glades, etc
...  and a lot of German reality trash. Note that only the shows marked with "free" are, well, free.

[**RTL2**](http://www.rtl2.de/video)
Detroit SWAT, Game of Thrones, the Stargate series, Torchwood
and again lots of no-brain German shows.

[**Pro7**](http://www.prosieben.de/video)
You're looking for pictures marked with "Ganze Folge", others are trailers and snippets.
2 Broke Girls, Simpsons, How I Met Your Mother, Grey's Anatomy, Supernatural, Two and a half Men, The Big Bang Theory, ...

[**VOX**](http://www.voxnow.de)
Arrow and CSI:NY are the only American Series marked as "free" here.

[**Phoenix**](http://www.phoenix.de)
Collaborative channel of ARD and ZDF focused on news and documentaries. It is easy to understand.

[**ARD.alpha**](http://www.br.de/fernsehen/ard-alpha/index.html)
Formerly named "BR.aplha" has some German lerning program: **GRIPS**, **Grundkurs Deutsch** and **Telekolleg Deutsch**. **Deutsch Klasse** is kind of a TV series. On the right hand side you find a box named "Sendungsinfo" with broadcasting times.

---

In general: the german TV is divided in two parts: the public broadcaster and the private broadcaster.
the public broadcaster consist of ARD and ZDF, where ARD also consists of the following regional stations (which meanwhile are receivable supraregional):
BR, HR, MDR, NDR, Radio Bremen, RBB, SR, SWR, WDR
also there are special channels of

- **ARD**: One, tagesschau24, ARD-alpha,
- **ZDF**: ZDFinfo, ZDFneo
- **ARD and ZDF together**: 3sat, Arte, funk, KiKA, Phoenix

These channels can mostly (there are big restrictions by law) be found online in the media centers (Mediathek) of ARD and ZDF, partly as live-streaming.

A more complete list can be found in the [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_stations_in_Germany) or, more actual, in the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernsehen_in_Deutschland). There also the private / commercial stations are listed, which mostly have media centers too.

Answer (score 17):

### Dictionaries

- [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?l=e) is a free, multilingual online dictionary. [Read this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/is-there-a-german-english-dictionary-in-pdf-or-that-works-offline/7578#7578) for more information about the dictionary and its offline version.
- [LEO dictionary](http://dict.leo.org): excellent online, free multilingual dictionary. They also have a great discussion forum and links to audio files for pronunciation.
- [canoonet](http://www.canoonet.eu/): Free German only dictionary. Great resource for orthography, morphology, and grammar, including conjugation tables. Cross-links to entries in DWDS, LEO, PONS, TheFreeDictionary, Wikipeida. and more.
- [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/): Free German only dictionary. Concise etymology entries. Many usage examples including quotes of "Die Zeit".
- [DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/): German only dictionary. The print edition used to be a reference dictionary for orthography. Links to audio samples of the *"Aussprachedatenbank der ARD"* for appropriate pronunciation.
- [Mac OS X Built in Dictionary](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-expanding-apple-dictionary-mac-only/): Can be expanded with 3rd party add ons and [made to talk](http://www.macworld.com/article/2038420/five-dictionary-tricks-i-cant-live-without.html) with high quality German voices. Is built into the OS and you can highlight any word on the web or in any text and get a definition in the correct language.
- [Hurraki](http://hurraki.de/): Dictionary for plain language
- [Wörterbuchnetz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/): Network of cross-referenced German dictionaries
- [Bildwörterbuch](http://www.bildwoerterbuch.com/): Dictionary with entries supported by images
- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite): a collaborative project to produce a free-content multilingual dictionary
- [Pons](http://pons.com/): free online dictionary by a major publisher of dictionaries; includes verb patterns.
- [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/): English-German Dictionary. Search 1,000,000,000 translations.
- [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php): A German-only dictionary specializing in idioms and other figures of speech
- [korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/): Portal für Rechtschreibung
- [DeepL.com](https://www.deepl.com/translator): Using AI, you can paste whole sentences and texts into it and get a very accurate, complete translations. You can also get alternative words or phrases proposed
- Offline: Dictionaries in text processing programs, for browsers
- Use Wikipedia as translation service for single words: search for the term in your one language, and check the left margin to see whether there is such an article in another language

### For Swiss pecularities of German

- [Schweizerisches Idiotikon](https://www.idiotikon.ch/woerterbuch/idiotikon-digital) (covers historic examples from the 15th century onwards, but also modern language)

Comment: I also like http://www.korrekturen.de/ a lot; especially the "Beliebte Fehler"-section.

Comment: I also like linguee.com

Comment: These are great resources, but does anyone know of a digital dictionary for Swiss German <-> German? This book was recommended to me but I would prefer a digital version with a search function: Heinz Gallmann - Zürichdeutsches Wörterbuch. I'm most interested in the dialect from Zürich.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that _Wikipedia as translation service_ is very valuable. This is especially true if you are looking for the correct terms of a certain subject in a foreign language even if you are not that professional in that subject.

Answer (score 15):

### Books

For a list of easy to read German literature please have a look at our reference question on that topic:

- **[Simple but interesting German literature](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature)**

The top voted answers to this question are listed here for your convenience:

- [**Momo**, Michael Ende](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/634/23)
- [**Die unendliche Geschichte**, Michael Ende](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/635/23)
- [**Die Vermessung der Welt**, Daniel Kehlmann](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/624/23)
- [**Tintenherz**, Cornelia Funke](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/622/23)
- [**Der Richter und sein Henker**, Dürrenmatt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1468/23)
- [**Krabat**, Otfried Preußler](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3837/23)
- [**Gut Gegen Nordwind**, Daniel Glattauer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4462/23)
- [**Russendisko**, Wladimir Kaminer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/644/23)
- [**Unser Dorf und der Krieg**, Käthe Recheis](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/646/23)

[Books in easy German](http://hurraki.de/blog/?s=b%C3%BCcher)

Comment: Here are some (automatically generated) vocabulary lists for some of these books, to help people to read them:

http://germanvocab.com

Comment: Just read *Sein und Zeit* from Heidegger, that's all you need for learning German

Answer (score 11):

### Websites

***needs content:*** add links to websites with a short description only if they are not an [online-dictionary](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german/9535#9535), or provide [online courses](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german/9534#9534), **and** the site is in other ways relevant to learning of the German language.

**Blogs**

- [German is easy!](https://yourdailygerman.com/)
- [Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2009/01/24/blog-und-weblog-in-canoonet/)
- [Marathon sprechen](https://www.marathonsprachen.com/blog/)
- [korrekturen.de - Weblog](https://www.korrekturen.de/weblog.shtml)
- [Sprachlupe](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122222738/https://sprachlupe.wordpress.com/)

**"Official" sites**

- [Deutsche Welle - Media Center - Deutschkurse](https://www.dw.com/de/media-center/deutschkurse/s-100816)
- Goethe-Institut <sup>[1](https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/ueb.html), `http://109.68.50.141/lrn/deindex.htm`</sup>
- [Bildungsserver - Resources](https://www.bildungsserver.de/onlineressourcen.html?fach=268), German as foreign/second language resources

**Online exercises**

- [IIK exercises](https://web.archive.org/web/20110818114807/http://www.iik.de/uebungen/uebungsseite/menue.html)
- [testedich.de - online tests](https://www.testedich.de/sprachen-tests-Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache.php?katb=0920)
- [Aufgaben vom Schubert-Verlag](https://www.aufgaben.schubert-verlag.de/)

**German grammar**

- [A Review of German Grammar by Bruce Duncan](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Grammatik.html)

  - A summary of German grammar for English speakers. From Dartmouth College.
- [Grimm Grammar](https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/index.html)

  - An overview of German grammar with examples in a fun fairy tail setting. From the Center for Open Educational Resources and Language Learning, The U. of Texas at Austen.
- [Die deutschplus-Grammatik](https://www.deutschplus.net/)

  - An outline of German grammar in German with translations in English and Greek. From LMU München.
- [A Foundation Course in Reading German](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/)

  - An online German textbook with emphasis on grammar. From the U. of Wisconsin–Madison.
- [LEOs deutsche Grammatik](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/grammar.xml?lang=de#id=0)

  - An outline of German grammar in German.
- [grammis Grammatisches Informationssystem](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/)

  - A reference resource for German grammar, in German. From the Leibniz Institute for the German Language.
- [Skripten und Materialien der VHS Passau](https://www.deutschkurse-passau.de/JM/index.php/downloads)

  - Has notes on grammar by CEFR level, A1–C1.

**German history**

- [GermanHistoryDocs](http://germanhistorydocs.ghi-dc.org/)

**Other Sites**

- [Deutsch für Dich](https://www.goethe.de/prj/dfd/de/home.cfm?wt_sc=dfd): Kostenlos gemeinsam Deutsch lernen (community)
- [BBC: Talk German](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/german/talk/): A lively introduction to the language in ten short parts.
- [germanvocab.com](http://ww12.germanvocab.com/): Automatically generated vocabulary lists of common words from the German books mentioned [above](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german/9536#9536).
- [German as foreign language - Resources](https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/daf-uebungen/index.html): Übungsdatenbank
- [Achtung Deutsch!](http://www.achtung-deutsch.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1): Online-Lernportal zum Deutschlernen
- [Cafe Deutsch](http://www.cafe-deutsch.de/): Sprachpraktische Übungen für Deutsch als Fremdsprache / Zweitsprache
- [DeutschLern.net](https://deutschlern.net/): Deutsch lernen online mit interaktiven Aufgaben
- [Land der Wörter](https://web.archive.org/web/20190604104348/http://www.land-der-woerter.de:80/index.html): Rätsel lösen und Deutsch lernen
- [Anglizism of the year](http://www.anglizismusdesjahres.de/): What english words do germans use?
- [Kompass Deutsch](http://www.dlc.fi/%7Epohalone/kompass/index.html): Kompass Deutsch is a learning material of German for children who have learned some elementary skills before. It is a complete material for the grades 7 - 9.
- [German list of symbols of the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen)
- [Bureaus for plain language](https://hurraki.de/blog/bueros-fuer-leichte-sprache/): Where are they allocated?
- [German-Grammar.de](https://www.german-grammar.de/) German grammar, Flash-based chat, fora, some literature, and overview of German culture.
- [Blebber](https://www.blebber.com/) German grammar, exercises and tables.
- [Word of The Hour](https://wordofthehour.org/) - A website that features one basic vocabulary word every hour with crowd-sourced translations by [Reddit community](https://www.reddit.com/r/Sprache/).
- [Online German Course](https://www.online-German-course.com).

**Other link collections**

- [Lexilogos](https://www.lexilogos.com/english/german_dictionary.htm)
- [Lexical Resources](https://www.clarin-d.net/de/)
- [Omniglot](https://www.omniglot.com/links/german.php)
- [University Michigan](https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/links/online-lessons/)

Answer (score 11):

### Newspapers

***needs content:*** add links to non regional German newspapers of general interest. For regional newspapers also see [Wikipedia: Liste deutscher Zeitungen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Zeitungen).

- [Die Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/index): weekly newspaper with concise and well researched articles on all topics. Known for an elaborate language which may not be suitable for beginners.
- [Der Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/): One of the major weekly newspapers. Politically left.
- [Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung (FAZ)](http://www.faz.net/): One of the major daily newspapers, not really restricted to Frankfurt. Politically conservative.
- [Süddeutsche Zeitung (SZ)](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/): One of the major daily newspapers, not really restricted to southern Germany. Politically left.
- [Bild](http://www.bild.de): high-circulation yellow press daily newspaper with an easy to understand but sometimes rather lurid language.
- [Stern](http://www.stern.de/): general-interest magazine.
- [Heise Online](https://www.heise.de/): publisher of several renowned fairly independent monthly journals on computing with a high standard of journalism (e.g. [c't](http://www.heise.de/ct/)).
- [Handelsblatt](http://www.handelsblatt.com/): A daily newspaper about business and economy. It also offers a wiki:
  [WirtschaftsWiki](http://www.handelsblatt.com/wirtschaftslexikon/)
- [Auto Motor und Sport](http://www.auto-motor-und-sport.de/): Automotive and motorsport news, test reports, and reviews.
- [Nachrichtenwerk](http://www.nachrichtenwerk.de/heute-wichtig.html), German news in plain language
- [Nachrichtenleicht](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/), German news in plain language
- [derStandard](https://derstandard.at/), Austrian national daily newspaper published in Vienna (no online subscription required).

Answer (score 8):

### (Online) courses

#### Free

- see answers to [Free online resources for beginner course](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/944/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course)
- [Wikibooks - German for English speakers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German): a free textbook for learning the German language
- [Wikibooks - German for non-English speakers](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regal:Deutsch_als_Fremdsprache): free textbooks for learning the German language
- [Duolingo](http://www.duolingo.com/): This is a website which offers free courses to learn different languages including German, Spanish, English, French, Italian, Portuguese, Irish, and Dutch. The associated apps for iOS and Android are featured and have a very good rating.

#### Paid

- [Babbel.com](http://www.babbel.com/learn-german-online): Babbel is the new way to learn a foreign language. The comprehensive learning system combines effective education methods with state-of-the-art technology. Basic courses are free.
- [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/): professional language learning for many devices
- [memrise](http://www.memrise.com/courses/english/german-2/). Great site for learning all kinds of languages, especially since users can create memes for words (i.e. custom images) to help you remembering. They also have an achievement system to increase motivation. Besides, most courses even feature pronunciation and are free to use.
- [busuu.com](https://www.busuu.com): Join the global language learning community, take language courses to practice reading, writing, listening and speaking and learn a new language.

Answer (score 6):

### Audio resources

***needs content:** URL, supported readers, free/commercial, short description, optional screenshot*

**Free**

- [Deutsch lernen mit Nachrichten](http://www.dw.de/deutsch-lernen/nachrichten/s-8030): you are getting LIVE-News read in slow voice and having the text to follow.
- [Vorleser.net](http://www.vorleser.net/): mp3 downloads, short stories in German.
- [librivox](https://librivox.org/): "Free public domain audiobooks - Read by volunteers from around the world." (includes many German texts)
- [Deutsch – warum nicht?](https://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/deutsch-warum-nicht/s-2548): An audio course by DW in four series of 26 episodes each. Developed in the early 90's so money is still in Deutschmarks. From beginner (A1) to intermediate (B2) level.
- [Radio D](https://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/radio-d/s-9671): Another audio course by DW. In two series of 26 episodes each. Beginner (A1-A2) level.
- [Mission Berlin](https://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/mission-europe/s-9831): Introductory level German audio course by DW. Part of the Mission Europe series which includes similar courses in French and Polish. 26 episodes.
- [ARD Audiothek](https://www.ardaudiothek.de/): Free audio pool of all public radio stations, website in German language only, wide range of files from radio play, audio book, over news, political podcasts, to comedy, fairy tales and children education. Depending of the chosen file, intermediate or more.

Answer (score 5):

### Software

***needs content:** URL, supported software/hardware, installation instruction,  short description, optional screenshot*

- [Duden Rechtschreibprüfung for MS Office](http://www.pcwelt.de/ratgeber/Die_Duden_Rechtschreibpruefung_9.0_Plus_fuer_Microsoft_Office_im_Test-Office-Software-7351568.html)
- [Vokabeltrainer-App](https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/ueb/vok.html): Android and iOS
- [Fluenz German](http://www.fluenz.com): Windows, Mac, Linux (via Wine), iOS and Android (beta)
- [Memorion](http://memorionsoft.blogspot.com/): Android (allows custom flashcards, automatically adjusting repetition intervals)
- [Dasbot](https://dasbot.yak.supplies/): Telegram bot for memorizing articles (noun genders); has frequency dictionary and spaced repetition

For the software-related basic problem of entering German characters on a keyboard layout not providing them, refer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/724/1696) and its answers.

Comment: I cannot recommend this app enough: https://memori-n.soft112.com/ There are some cards available and you can easily add your own. When answering the flash cards, you can rate how well you knew the vocabulary and based on that, an interval is determined when you get asked again.

Answer (score 5):

### Video resources

- [Easy German](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbxb2fqe9oNgglAoYqsYOtQ) (Youtube, Patreon) is a free Youtube channel that teaches German with interviews on the streets. Each video comes with subtitles in German and English. They also create videos explaining topics on German language, covering not so much basic grammar as pragmatic help with peculiarities like idioms, modal particles, special vocabulary etc. Very likeable hosts, and a great resource to listen to German as it's spoken on the street. There's also paid additional online learning material available via their Patreon.
- [Ticket nach Berlin](http://www.goethe.de/ticketnachberlin) (online, free, [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLquImyRfMt6esqE6C4RdOeg0h0IBeYWri)) is a niveau B1 video series from the Goethe-Institut and Deutsche Welle for those who want to learn German
- [Extr@ auf Deutsch](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLM45RE_YsqS5-S58HSmYOhu2m-tRul9jW) (YouTube) is a 13 episode series designed for learners of German in High School. (There are also English, French and Spanish versions if you're interested.) Most conversation is in German, and German subtitles are available.
- [Harry – Gefangen in der Zeit](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLs7zUO7VPyJ6Ufol7Z4FfkCviaETvl3c8) (YouTube) is a 100 episode series created by DW. For beginner (A1) to intermediate (B1) levels.
- [Nicos Weg](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLs7zUO7VPyJ5DV1iBRgSw2uDl832n0bLg) (YouTube) is a set of three series, 76 short episodes each, also created by DW. For beginner (A1) to intermediate (B1) levels. Most conversation is in German.
- [Mein Weg nach Deutschland](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLquImyRfMt6esqE6C4RdOeg0h0IBeYWri) (YouTube) is a miniseries of 8 short episodes, from the Goethe-Institut. Intermediate level.
- [DeutschPlus](https://www.youtube.com/c/Deutschplus) (YouTube) is a channel dealing in short lessons with intermediate to advanced topics (B2 .. C2)

Comment: I would like to add the youtube channel [Deutschretter](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUsM8ecCRI_s7f6fXZ7SGLw) as a resource of very helpful videos.

Answer (score 5):

### Podcasts

- [Deutsch-perfekt](http://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/)
- [Deutsche Welle Podcasts](http://www.dw.de/deutsch-lernen/podcasts-newsletter/s-11696)
- [DaZPod](http://dazpod.de/en/)
- [SlowGerman](http://www.slowgerman.com/)
- [Duden | Podcast](http://www.duden.de/podcast)
- [CoffeeBreak German](https://radiolingua.com/category/coffee-break-german/)
- [Deutsch Podcast](https://deutsch-podcast.com)

Answer (score 2):

### Textbooks

***needs content:*** Grammar books that teach you the grammar of the language with theory and exercises.

- [Hueber Deutsch als Fremdsprache: Deutsche Übungsgrammatik für Fortgeschrittene, ISBN 978-3-19-007448-8](https://shop.hueber.de/en/uebungsgrammatik-fuer-fortgeschrittene.html)
- [Bruce Donaldson: German - An Essential Grammar, Routledge 2007](https://www.routledge.com/German-An-Essential-Grammar/Donaldson/p/book/9780415366021), ISBN 9780415366021)

  - 1st edition seems [available for academic purpose](https://www.academia.edu/5595124/German_Essential_Grammar)
  - [2nd edition 2015](https://routledgetextbooks.com/textbooks/9781138785816/) by [Martin Durrell, Katrin Kohl, Claudia Kaiser and Gudrun Lotus](https://www.routledge.com/Essential-German-Grammar/Durrell-Kohl-Loftus-Kaiser/p/book/9781138785816), ISBN 9781138785816
- ...

Also see

- [Books like "English Grammar in use" for the German language](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/books-like-english-grammar-in-use-for-the-german-language)