# German dictionary with native audio for Android?

Tags: resource, dictionary

Are there any regularly updated high quality German/English dictionary app available with native pronunciation?  I see a lot of free ones but they don't have audio.

The PONS dictionary website uses text-to-speech software for their pronunciation right?  I suppose it's the same with the app.

Comment: you might also find some hints here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Answer (score 2):

Try the free [dict.cc app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.dict.dictcc). You can download the abridged dictionary or the full one with >1'000'000 entries (~800mb) once the app is installed. The text part of the dictionary works with or without internet, but to actually use the audio recordings (most words have native recordings and for those that do not there's a computerized one) you'll need to be connected to the internet.