# Resources for learning verb tenses with short example sentenses

Tags: verb, learning, tense

I wish to learn verbs with their tense forms for general conversation. I tried to use the verb tables, but I am not able to memorise them. I think it would help me if I learn these forms alongwith small example sentenses.
I want to learn basic tenses for now (present, present perfect, past,  and future)

I found one at - [Verbs with examples at about.com](http://german.about.com/library/blstrverbs5.htm)

I want more resources like this. I would like to practice when I am offline. In such case an App (Andoroid preferably) would be really useful.

> Are there any resources (mobile apps or websites etc.) like the one I mentioned?

Comment: So do you need further help or are you satisfied with the site you found?

Comment: I need further help. :-)

Comment: what sort of additional help do you need, Amol? @Sam (<- just so he gets a notification).

Comment: Hi Mark. I want more resources like this. I would like to practice when I am offline. In such case an App (Andoroid preferably) would be really useful. I would also like to know if there are additional web resources like the one I mentioned.

Comment: Did you see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german  ?

Comment: What about this one [here](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/duw/app/enindex.htm).

Comment: You want AnkiDroid (available on other platforms too). You can also download a number of existing German language decks from [https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/german](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/german)

Comment: @pdah, I do use AnkiDroid. But have not found the specific cards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such resource for your special case. You can verify this by searching the internet, for instance with these search words `learn deutsch online verb tenses examples` or `Deutsch lernen Verb Zeitformen Übungen`.

Instead you will find lots of good online learning tools, which either explain you the tenses and give only some examples, or give you verb form tables without examples or with just one example.

For learning, you should first learn the basics with some examples. Then consolidation of newly acquired knowledge comes step by step with permanent exercising and repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this set at Memrise:

http://www.memrise.com/course/47458/100-most-common-german-verbs-used-in-all-tenses/

I'm not sure about downloading offline or not, and I personally prefer to do them on the computer, but it's very helpful for constructing those really crazy verb tenses.