# Is there a site for learning German like this one?

Tags: learning, online-resource

I tried to find sites where everything is sorted nicely, like grammar > present simple > other things etc., then vocabulary > commonly used words > parts of human body, town > food > other words.

Is there anything like that, because that's how I learned English and it's the best way for me to learn a language?

Also, I don't want things like Duolingo and other interactive things because they are really slow and you can't learn more than few words from it.

Answer (score 0):

[Lingolía](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/) (available in German, English, Spanish, French, Italian and Russian) provides both grammar and vocabulary.
Certainly not complete, but that should be sufficient enough to get you started.

Comment: This should go there: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/9534/