# Is there a German Dictionary with audio support?

Tags: pronunciation, dictionary, audio

I have recently started learning German and I find it really hard to remember how certain words are pronounced and what are their articles (German articles are crazy :D).

Is there any application or tool which has German words written with articles and pronunciations?

Comment: Yes, leo has audio for all it's entries. http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/

Comment: The additional -s and -en is the plural ending. You have to learn it for every single word, though there are some rules to guess it.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/german-dictionary-with-detailed-declensions-audio-pronunciations-and-ipa - also see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/does-a-a-free-online-talking-dictionary-of-german-pronunciation-exist http://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/23

Comment: See also [this answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/28730/1696) for genitive and plural endings in dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, almost all online dictionaries provide the audio for the word, you searched for.

Here are some of them;

**Langenscheidt**

https://de.langenscheidt.com/

**Pons**

http://en.pons.com

**Dict.cc**

http://www.dict.cc/

**Duden**

http://www.duden.de/

Intuitively, there is a "audio button" for the pronouncation of the word directly right or left of the searched word.When you click it, you get what you want.

This screenshot below is from Langenscheidt;

[image]

If you have further questions, please leave a comment below.