# Wo/Wie kann ich meinen Wortschatz erweitern?

Tags: learning, resource, vocabulary

Ich lerne gerade die Lektionen für die B2-Prüfung. Trotzdem fühle ich, dass ich noch mehr Vokabeln lernen muss. Ich suche jetzt Ressourcen dafür, deutsche Wörter zu lernen.

Comment: Wenn du B2 machst solltest du authentische Texte lesen. Zeitungen, Journale, Sachbücher, Romane... da werden genug Wörter drin sein.

Comment: Ich habe Deine zweite, bisher unbeantwortete Frage entfernt, da sie sich hinreichend von der ersten unterscheidet und mehrere Fragen pro Frage der Übersicht schaden. Du kannst die Frage jedoch gerne als getrennte Frage erneut stellen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Damals, nach dem Krieg, ...**

OK, das könnte sich jetzt etwas langweilig anhören, aber zu Schulzeiten habe ich es geliebt, im DCE zu schmökern. Das war halt total ungerichtet - dutzende Themen auf einer Seite! - und hat auch wenig Kontext mitgebracht, aber der Umstand, dass es ein einsprachiges Wörterbuch ist, hat mich automatisch immer wieder gezwungen, Vokabeln zu wiederholen. Parallel dazu habe ich englischsprachige Bücher verschlungen - hauptsächlich Science-Fiction-Romane. Und zuguterletzt: Internet-Chat mit Muttersprachlern. All dies hat mein Leseverstehen, wie auch meine Schreibfertigkeit im Englischen von vielleicht B1 aus der gymnasialen Oberstufe auf vielleicht C1 gehoben, ohne dass ich je das Gefühl gehabt hätte, ich müsste Vokabeln *pauken*.

**Reden wir deutsch...**

"*Jaja, aber ich will doch gar nicht Englisch lernen!!!*" - schon klar :) Aber all das was ich für mein entspanntes Vokabeltraining in Englisch verwendet habe, gibt es natürlich auch im Deutschen.

Vielleicht nimmst Du nicht unbedingt den Duden, der ist deutlich langweiliger als das DCE mit seinen Grafiken und Themen-Specials, aber schau doch zum Beispiel regelmäßig in die deutschsprachige Wikipedia und schau Dir die [exzellenten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Exzellente_Artikel) und [lesenswerten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lesenswerte_Artikel) Artikel an. Riesiger Themenquerschnitt, multimedial, und die Qualität in diesen Kategorien ist wirklich sehr sehr hoch - sowohl inhaltlich als auch sprachlich. Das ist auf jeden Fall den "Zufälligen Artikeln" vorzuziehen ;) Wenn Du bestimmte Themengebiete bevorzugst, kannst Du mittels [dieser Webseite](https://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php) (auch) in der deutschsprachigen Wikipedia Schnittmengen von Kategorien bilden, z.B. [Exzellente Artikel in der Kategorie Astronomie](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=de&categories=Wikipedia%3AExzellent%0D%0AAstronomie%7C6&comb%5Bunion%5D=1). Beziehungsweise haben die verlinkten Spezialseiten auch große Verzeichnisse, die nach Themengebieten sortiert sind.

Bei den Büchern empfehle ich Dir nichts, weil das ja sehr vom persönlichen Geschmack abhängt - Zeitungen, Nachrichten und Online-Ressourcen wurden ja bereits in anderen Antworten genannt. Schau auch mal [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/15481), da werden viele Ressourcen zentral gesammelt.

Einen guten deutschsprachigen Chat kann ich Dir leider auch nicht empfehlen, meine IRC-Zeit ist lang vorüber und konzentrierte sich halt primär auf englischsprachige Chats :( Ich bin mir aber sicher, dass sich so etwas sehr schnell über die Suchmaschine Deiner Wahl finden lassen kann - auch hier wieder in Abhängigkeit Deiner Interessengebiete.

Viel Erfolg!

Answer (score 0):

Für leichte Vokabeln: Online Zeitungsportale regelmäßig lesen, Filme (gegebenenfalls mit Untertiteln) sehen. Sind zwar mehr als 100 Wörtern, aber direkt verfügbar. Falls dich beispielsweise IT Nachrichten interessieren: www.golem.de, haben öfter kürzere Nachrichten. Ansonsten einfach mal nach "Lernbücher Deutsch als Fremdsprache" suchen.

Answer (score 0):

Als der Kommentar auf deiner Post schon erwähnt hat, könntest Du einfach authentische Texte lesen. Für mich persönlich ist Erinnerung nicht möglich, also ich musste Inhalt und Webseite finden, die mir interessieren.

[Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw.com/de/themen/s-9077) ist eine tolle Hilfsquelle für Deutschlerner zu jeder Stufe. Direkt auf der Webseite gibt's eine Menge Nachrichten und Artikel. Es gibt aber auch [Inhalt nur für Deutschlerner](http://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/s-2055). Langsam Gesprochene Nachrichten hat mir wahrscheinlich meist dabei geholfen, meinen Wortschatz zu expandieren. Mach Dir keine Sorge, wenn Du am Anfang nicht verstehst; mach einfach weiter und vielleicht nächstes mal verstehst Du es. Ich höre mich fast jeden Tag die Nachrichten an, und jetzt kann ich fast 100% verstehen, ohne die Podcast anzuhalten. Mein Deutsch ist auch B2.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde dir empfehlen, zu überlegen, welche Themen dich am meisten interessieren. Wenn du dich zum Beispiel für Computer interessierst und häufig etwas dazu liest, dann such dir doch einfach etwas passendes auf Deutsch. Für Computer-News empfehle ich beispielsweise www.heise.de. Da sind viele Nachrichten zum Thema Computer und Programmieren. Wenn du nach Nachrichten suchst, guck dir mal www.tagesschau.de an. 
Ich hoffe, ich konnte dir helfen!