# German lexical chunks and collocations

Tags: translation

I'm an "advanced beginner" in German, and am wondering if anyone knows of any books or articles (preferably but not necessarily written for English speakers) containing lists and explanations of  German lexical chunks and/or collocations, with English translations, or vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for learning German](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

Answer (score 1):

A good resource in my opinion for these things is Martin Durrell: *Using German*.