# podcast with its text for B1 level or a higher level

Tags: listening-comprehension

I want sites, which give me free podcasts with their texts and if possible with English translations to improve my listening skills. I'm learning German through listening. It's effective and fun way of learning German.

Comment: Welcome. Did you take a look at [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)? I think there one can find a comprehensive list of that what you need.

Comment: No. i searched a lot in different Q&A sites & google but i didn't find  good site(s). anyway thanks

Comment: That linked question is also of this site. There *podcasts* is addressed and in the answers you will find them.