# German Television

Tags: learning, online-resource

I learn German the best when I listen/watch it, so I've been looking for some german dubbed and subbed movies and tv shows. Sadly, I can't find much.

Are there any sites that people know of where I can find German dubbed/subbed movies and tv shows like Disney, cartoons, etc?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you see our list here: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8655/?

Comment: You could try to set up a German Netflix account (or rather a Netflix account and use PureVPN to simulate that you are in Germany).

Comment: It actually /is/ a duplicate, but: There is no "movies and tv shows" category in the "Resources..." page.

Comment: That is surprising. Basically every international movie comes in a dubbed version for the German market. Also on television every movie, documentary or interview has at least a simple German voice-over. This is actually extremely annoying for anyone (like me) who prefers watching movies in their original language. It is probably also the reason why so many Germans (at least those above a certain age) have problems with communicating in foreign languages. In other countries you will find a lot more OV with subtitles than in Germany and a lot more people who can speak proper English.

Comment: Right. I wouldn't dare and say you could learn a foreign language by watching TV only, but it certainly helps. Scandinavian countries as well as the Netherlands are good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite Disney stuff, but very informative:
http://mediathek.daserste.de/

Comment: Und da gibt es brauchbare Untertitel?

Comment: Yes, for some of the entries there is even German subs for the deaf. Those entries are marked with a "UT" (look for this button to activate subs in the player). The subs are, however, not literal translations so might or migth not be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't start with Disney ;)

Start with something German..... Below a small example list of movies of popular children's literature from YouTube

> Erich Kästner: Emil und die Detektive + English sub-titles (Classic from 1931)
> https://youtu.be/CFNnzX1hPx0
>
> Paul Maar: Am Samstag kam das Sams zurück
> https://youtu.be/hfMw4OaDU-E
>
> Max Kruse: Urmel aus dem Eis
> https://youtu.be/Fzm_aPR_KP0
>
> Tilde Michels: Kleiner König Kalle Wirsch
> https://youtu.be/maX8s8IFlZ0

If you start from there, you will find lots of other movies.

Comment: I'd not recommend Urmel for beginners. Some characters speak fast, some animals have speech defects as part of their character, and there may be bavarian dialect in some character speech.

Comment: I actually recommended that movie/book for exactly that reason ;) A big part of the plot is watching the animals learning German and their mishaps with that.

Comment: Hast Du die Untertitel mal eingeschaltet? Für das Sams habe ich es versucht und kann sagen, es ist unbrauchbarer Schrott. Der Titelsong wird mit Brüderle in Verbindung gebracht. Sind die anderen Empfehlungen von ähnlicher Güte?

Comment: Die von YouTube erzeugten Untertitel sind bekanntermassen Murks und können allerhöchstens zur Erheiterung beitragen. Einzig "Emil und die Detektive" hat "richtige" englische Untertitel. Allerdings war auch nicht ausschliesslich nach Untertiteln gefragt - Auch wenn die zugegebenermassen für den Zweck sinnvoll wären.

Comment: @Robert I’m pretty sure that there is little to no Bavarian dialect to be found in there. However, some characters have clear Swabian influence, the *Puppenkiste* being based in Augsburg (Swabia).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re located in Europe there’s a good chance that you’ll be able to receive many German television channels for free via satellite. If you don‘t have a satellite dish, it may require a one-time 100+ € investment. 
The biggest selection is available on [SES Astra, 19.2° East](http://www.astra.de/16791786/senderpakete?free=yes&pay=no&mode=tv&language%5B%5D=5&sd=yes&hd=yes). 
Many cable providers also offer foreign language packets, but that depends a lot on your location (and probably becomes more costly quickly). 
You should at least receive broadcasts from [Deutsche Welle TV](http://www.dw.com), the German state-funded foreign TV service, partially in English or local languages.

A lot of movies released on discs (DVD/BD) that are intended for sale in “Region 2” (i.e. Europe) will feature audio tracks for multiple languages, often including German. If you don’t have any, your friends, local library or next flea-market may and the usual online shops definitely do.

Most public and ad-funded TV stations have video on demand services for their (original) programming, at least for the last week or so, but to access them you usually need to be “in Germany”. That means either the IP address that your service provider assigned to your account or the one of a proxy you’re using needs to be considered German (or Austrian or Swiss). The established term for these VOD portals is [*Mediathek*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediathek_(Fernsehen)) in German.

- [ARD](http://www.ardmediathek.de/tv) – federal public network from Germany
- [ZDF](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek#/hauptnavigation/startseite) – central public station from Germany
- [ORF](http://tvthek.orf.at/) – federal public network from Austria
- [SRF](http://www.srf.ch/play/tv) – public station from Switzerland
- [3Sat](http://www.3sat.de/mediathek/) – Austrian-German-Swiss public collaboration
- [Arte](http://www.arte.tv/guide/de/plus7/) – French-German public collaboration
- [DW](http://www.dw.com/de/media-center/s-100813) – state-funded station not available inside Germany
- [Kika](http://www.kika.de/videos/index.html), also [Tivi](http://www.tivi.de/mediathek/) – public station for kids from Germany
- [Nickelodeon](http://www.nick.de/videos) – trashy kids TV
- [RTL group](http://www.nowtv.de), also [Clipfish](http://www.clipfish.de/) – more or less trashy private TV
- [Pro7Sat1 group](http://www.7tv.de/), also [My Video](http://www.myvideo.de/) – same-same, but different
- There are [more, smaller networks](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutschsprachiger_Fernsehsender) that probably also offer videos of their broadcasts.

If you’re looking for torrent trackers, download or streaming sites beyond Youtube, I have no idea, but you may be interested in the following.

- [Dokumonster](http://dokumonster.de/) – lots of documentaries from different sources
- [My Spass](http://www.myspass.de/) – mainstream comedy
- [Netzkino](http://www.netzkino.de/) and [DZango](http://dzango.de/) – B and C movies for free, legal

If you’re actually looking for specific content suggestions, then I must have misread the question.

Comment: Und wie sieht es da mit Untertiteln aus?