# Difference among werten, bewerten, auswerten?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Kann jemand mir helfen, um zwischen 'werten, bewerten und auswerten' unterscheiden? Bei meinem Wörterbuch geht es alle gleiche Bedeutung.

Comment: Ein besseres Wörterbuch finden? Anregungen gibt es [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1696).

Answer (score 3):

**aus**werten klingt sehr objektiv: man wertet in einem Arbeitsvorgang eine Menge an Daten aus und kommt zu einem Ergebnis. Wenn 2 Personen die gleiche Sache auswerten, dann sollte das Ergebnis sehr ähnlich, wenn nicht sogar gleich ausfallen.

Man könnte zum Beispiel Einschaltquoten auswerten. Oder Besucherzahlen auf einer Webseite.

**be**werten klingt eher subjektiv und kann auch einfach die persönliche Meinung sein. Wenn 2 Personen die gleiche Sache bewerten, kann das Ergebnis sehr unterschiedlich ausfallen - und es bedarf auch keiner Arbeit, etwas zu bewerten. Das kann auch aus dem Bauch heraus geschehen.

Man könnte zum Beispiel einen Film berwerten. Oder ein Musikalbum.

Ein klarer Unterschied zwischen werten und bewerten fällt mir nicht ein. Ich würde werten allerdings immer als Synonym für **be**werten und nicht als Synonym für auswerten verstehen.

Es gibt einige unklare Fälle - zum Beispiel werden Klausuren im Normalfall vom Lehrer nicht ausgewertet sondern bewertet.

Comment: Man könnte hinzufügen: *werten* hat oft mehr den Vorgang im Auge, *bewerten* oft mehr das Ergebnis. Ähnlich wäre die *Wertung* eher der Vorgang, *Bewertung* eher das Ergebnis. Aber man würde auch viele Beispiele finden, wo dies nicht strikt so gehandhabt wird und die Wörter in der Tat praktisch synonym verwendet werden.

Answer (score 0):

"Werten" meint "worth" oder "value."

Die andere Worten beziehen sich auf eine Wertmessung.

Eine **Aus**wertung ist eine "quantitative" Wertmessung auf Wert. (oder Beschatzung).

Eine **Be**wertung ist eine "qualitative" Wertmessung.