# Stärkung vs Verstärkung

Tags: difference

Could anyone please tell me the difference between Stärkung and Verstärkung? When to use which one, perhaps with a few examples?

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: They are mostly synonymous. Verstärkung is more common and usually refers to material things, make a bridge stronger, add people to a group, thus strengthening it. Stärkung is more for intangible things like Zusammenhalt. Stärkung can also be used to describe a snack.

Comment: Start on this [answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1696) and its siblings for a start. DWDS should provide what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hier einige Beispielsätze, in denen die Wörter *Stärkung* und *Verstärkung* in typischer Weise eingesetzt sind:

> Nach dem Schlittschuhlaufen aß Max zur Stärkung eine Fritattensuppe.
>
> "Kleine Stärkung gefällig?" fragte die Hostesse und überreichte ihm einen Müsliriegel.
>
> Die Stärkung der Zivilgesellschaft ist eines unserer wichtigsten Ziele.
>
> Bundesregierung erwägt Stärkung der Verbraucherrechte
>
> Zur Verstärkung unseres Teams suchen wir einen fähigen Suppenkoch.
>
> Kölner Polizei lehnt Verstärkung an Silvester ab
>
> Diese Brückenkonstruktion ist instabil. Eine Verstärkung des Tragwerks ist dringend notwendig.
>
> Negative Verstärkung in der Hundeerziehung - was ist das?

Nota bene: *Stärkung* und *Verstärkung* können in diesen Beispielsätzen nicht ausgetauscht werden. Man verstünde die Sätze dann zwar noch, doch ein Muttersprachler würde spüren, dass irgend etwas mit den Sätzen nicht stimmt, und ein Redakteur würde die Wortwahl korrigieren.

(These examples, by the way, confirm the short theoretical explanation given by @problemofficer in his comment to the original question.)

Weitere, sehr spezifische Themenfelder erschließen sich, wenn man statt der Nomen die Verben nimmt:

> Der Tonmeister sagt zum Tontechniker: "Die Bässe sind zu schwach, kannst du die noch etwas verstärken?"
>
> Die Büglerin stärkt das Hemd.