# I want to mean "I might have broken something" in german

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to say "I might have accidentally broken the internet connection.". Is my following sentence fine?

> Vielleicht habe ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung gebrochen.

Comment: Hast Du ein Wörterbuch besucht? Was hat es gesagt?

Comment: @userunknown du *besuchst* Wörterbücher? Ich besuche i.a. nur Personen und Orte.

Comment: @userunknown welche Wörterbücher übersetzen die Saetze, kannst du welche empfehlen bitte?

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/ is pretty good.

Comment: @DaF-Student See this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/1696) and its answers.

Comment: @Stephie: Selbstverständlich. Ich besuche auch GL und SO, die Mona Lisa, Konzerte, u.v.a. mehr.

Comment: @DaF-Student: Erstmal habe ich an Wörter gedacht, und dict.leo.org, in der Tat. https://www.deepl.com/translator liefert auch ganze Sätze:  "Ich könnte versehentlich die Internetverbindung unterbrochen haben."

Answer (score 4):

- The use of 'broken' doesn't translate to the German 'gebrochen' in this case. You could use 'unterbrochen' (interrupted), but you probably want to translate 'broken' to the casual-sounding "kaputt gemacht".
- "Vielleicht" and "versehentlich" seem kind of redundant.

So, something like: Ich glaube, ich habe aus Versehen die Internetverbindung kaputt gemacht.

Comment: "kaputt machen" ist zwar die richtige Übersetzung, klingt aber scheußlich. Mir fällt aber auch kein gutes Synonym ein. "Unterbrochen" ist ein guter Vorschlag, auch wenn das in der Tat eine andere Bedeutung hat. Man bräuchte hier mit Sicherheit mehr Kontext. +1 anyway

Comment: "zerstören" wäre ein Synonym zu "kaputt machen", klingt aber in diesem Kontext auch nicht wirklich gut..

Comment: Der Kontext ist glaube ich nicht ganz klar, das ist das Problem. Wenn es als Scherz unter Freunden gemeint ist, koennte man beispielsweise "gegrillt" nehmen - je nach Freundeskreis gibt es hier noch viele andere, passende Woerter. In einem formalen Kontext klingt "unterbrochen" schon ganz gut.

Comment: "klingt aber scheußlich" Kommt drauf an, ob man es locker meint, was ich beim englischen Original rausdeuten würde. "Unterbrochen" ist für mich nicht das gleiche (und auch im Vergleich zum Englischen deutlich technischer).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mean *»temporarily interrupt«* I would propose one of these:

> - Es könnte sein, dass ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung gekappt
>     habe.
> - [Es] mag sein, dass ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung gekappt
>     habe.

[*»kappen«*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kappen) means to cut, *[»unterbrechen«](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterbrechen)* to interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

*I have broken smth* wird im Deutschen zu *Ich habe etwas kaputt gemacht* übersetzt.

Daher würde ich Deinen Satz übersetzen als

> Es könnte sein, dass ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung kaputt gemacht habe.

Comment: Kannst du mir bitte einige website empfehlen, damit ich Übersetzung szwischen beiden Sprachen(deutsch und english) vergleichen kann?

Answer (score 1):

```
Vielleicht habe ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung gebrochen.
```

Du kannst schon rein technisch betrachtet keine "Internetverbindung brechen". Du kannst eine Internetverbindung trennen ("disconnect") oder, physisch, das Kabel "brechen". In letzterem Fall empfiehlt sich aber "knicken" oder "abknicken"; um ein Kabel brechen zu können, müsste es unflexibel sein - wie z.B. ein Brett oder ein Stück Brot.

It depends on what you want to say. Did you disconnect the internet? Then say

```
Vielleicht habe ich versehentlich die Internetverbindung getrennt.
```

Or did you actually break the physical connection? Then say

```
Vielleicht habe ich versehentlich das Internetkabel ...
  ... zerstört.
  ... zerknickt.
  ... geknickt.
  ... kaputt gemacht.
  ... abgeknickt.
```

Aside from that, if you want to stay closer to the original meaning of "I might have accidentally broken the internet connection", I would suggest the following:

```
Es wäre möglich, dass ich aus Versehen das Internetkabel abgeknickt habe.
```

That phrasing would better serve to transmit a feeling of guilt, which (in my opinion) can be slightly heard in your sentence (I would put the emphasis on "might". Of course, you could very well mean something else, I don't know the context.)

Answer (score -2):

> Ich habe vielleicht versehentlich die Internetverbindung unterbrochen.