# German cartoons to improve my German

Tags: learning, speaking

I want to watch free German cartoons to improve my German level. Which German cartoons do you suggest me and where can I find them freely?

Comment: Google for "deutsche Comics".

Comment: Try youtube. Many english cartoons are also available in german.

Comment: Look for *Zeichentrick* and *Zeichentrickfilm*.

Comment: Maybe you are also interested in *Puppentrickfilm*, most famous the MDR *Sandmännchen*, *Bernd das Brot*, and the *Augsburger Puppenkiste*.

Comment: I always find Mickey Mouse / Donald Duck very helpful for learning other languages. Learning German from (older?) Mickey Mouse magazines would be a particularly good idea because the famous **Erika Fuchs** who was responsible for the translations from 1951 to 1988 (!!!) used a language that is both formally correct and still adequate for everyday situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On youtube you can watch episodes of the popular cartoon **Die Biene Maja** https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLdHRcaRTf6cie56jn0JUsHVGMMSU4AqY-&v=m04EW-J84nQ

Comment: This should got there: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15315/9183