# Resources to learn German?

Tags: learning

I would like to start learning german online, but I don't know where to do it, I made a seach in this community, but I not found nothing, someone have something like this? https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian a little place where are listed few resources concernning to the language?

A little website where I'll can start to learn the leanguage maybe? I apreciate your help in advance. Thanks

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Comment: Perfect! is completely that I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please give your question a title that gives readers a clue what it's about.

Comment: Done @RHa I've change the title