# Duden zeigt nicht immer Beispiele zum nachgeschlagenen Wort

Tags: dictionary

Ich möchte Beispiele von einem Substantiv in Sätzen sehen, aber Duden zeigt nicht welche zum nachgeschlagenen Wort. Duden ist der bekannteste Wortschatz Deutschlands.

Gibt es eine Webseite, auf der immer Beispiele zum nachgeschlagenen Wort gefunden werden können?

Comment: Eine Antwort findest du hier https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1691

Comment: dwds und vor allem seine korpussuche

Comment: @c.p. well this one is not so general, as it refers only to dictionaries with examples for each and every word.

Comment: @Dan Theoretisch hast du recht. Aber die Existenz eines nicht da gelisteten Wörterbuchs, die solche Bedingung erfüllt, bezweifle ich.

Comment: Kannst Du bitte ein oder zwei Beispiele nennen, die Du im Duden nachgeschlagen hast, und zu denen es keinen Beispielsatz gab? Ich möchte damit ein anderes Worterbuch testen, bevor ich es Dir vorschlage.

Comment: Ich arbeite immer mit dwds.de.  Links gibt es eine recht ausführliche Liste mit Beispielen pro Einzelbedeutung. Rechts gibt es dazu die "Korpustreffer." Ich schaue mir meistens sofort die "Referenz- und Zeitungskorpora (aggregiert, frei)" an, weil die Beispiele dort aktueller sind als im sogenannten "Kernkorpus". Sie sind nach Aktualität sortiert. Sehr nützlich ist vor allem auch das "DWDS-Wortprofil", weiter unten im Artikel verlinkt. Dort kann man z.B. sehen, mit welchen Objekten oder Subjekten sich ein Verb typischerweise verbindet.

Comment: (weiter...) Beispiel für "Waggon": https://www.dwds.de/wb/Waggon . Dazu das aktuellste "Kernkorpus": https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=korpus21;q={Waggon,Wagon} . Dazu das "aggregierte Zeitungskorpus": https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=public;q=%7BWaggon%2CWagon%7D - und das "Wortprofil": https://www.dwds.de/wp?q=Waggon&comp-method=diff&comp=&pos=2&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=100&view=table

Comment: Die Links funktionieren teilweise nicht. Leider werde ich aus der Hilfe nicht schlau. Dort steht "Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)". Was wäre bei [link] einzutragen? Und wieso steht der eigentliche Link dann hinter [Link] in runden Klammern?

Comment: Ach lass es, wer will wird den Lenk schon manuell kopieren und einfügen.

Comment: @Dan Was meinst du mit korpussuche?

Comment: @RalfJoerres Fragen nach stackoverflow froums müssten im Meta forum bzw. German Language Meta gestellt werden