# German nouns' precise form of writing

Tags: noun, grammatical-number, writing

Where can I find German dictionary which write words (nouns) with article and plural in this form — das Abitur, -e

Comment: Bookstores, libraries, internet

Comment: Björn Friedrich, that is not really helping. Could you recommend some?

Comment: @infinitezero  I think Björn implicitely wanted to criticize OP for lack of demonstration of own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: I think this question implicitely asks for such a dictionary. Sure, there are hundreds on the internet. But which one is a good one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution (via the internet) is perhaps the dict.cc dictionary (https://www.dict.cc)

When you click on the German word you usually get the necessary morphological information displayed, like here for *Hose*

[image]