# Online-Wörterbuch / Lernmaterialien ab C1-Level

Tags: learning, dictionary, online-resource

Gibt es ein Online-Deutsch-Wörterbuch, in dem steht, ob die Wörter geeignet für ein formelles Schreiben sind?

Ich möchte die C1-Prüfung machen und es ist dringend notwendig, dass ich meine Schreibfähigkeiten verbessere.

Comment: Was ist ein "formelles Schreiben"? Standard-Deutsch oder Briefe mit Behörden? Der Duden hat die Eigenschaft "Gebrauch" und z.B. bei https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Klimbim notiert "umgangssprachlich". Allerdings finde ich die Angabe "Kartenspiele" bei https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ramsch_Spielrunde_Skat nur bedingt hilfreich. DWDS gibt lediglich eine Bedeutung wie "salopp" https://www.dwds.de/wb/Klimbim bzw. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ramsch#1, was gemeinhin als informell gilt. Ist sowas gemeint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Es wird womöglich nicht leicht meine Frage zu beantworten. Mit formelles Schreiben meine ich nur Dinge, die in einer Deutsch Prüfung (C1 Niveau oder hoher) nicht als ein Fehler markiert werden. Abtönungspartikel und Redensarten sind akkeptable beim mündlichen Teil der Prüfung und in der echten Sprache natürlich aber können beim schriftlich Teil zur Durchfuhrung führen.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ At first glance there seems to be some useful resources but as far as my specific question is concerned, I did not see anything helpful. What I and other higher level German learners need (and probably young adults as well) is a resource that distinguishes parts of speech that are not acceptable in formal writing of the Standard German variety for a language exam, such as the ÖSD.

Comment: @tom Well, most dictionaries have a notice on particular words like _colloquial, ugs._ or such, this is what you shouldn't use in a written exam. For the opposite there's usually no such notice would be there, but that's not a definite confirm that the word would be appropriate. I believe there's no such thing available. I'd recommend you should hold on with the recommended vocabulary list for C1.

Comment: In einer C1-Prüfung geht es darum, sich sprachlich angemessen ausdrücken zu können. Ein einzelnes unangemessenes oder sogar falsches Wort ändert daran gar nichts.

Comment: @tom: "Durchfuhrung" gibt es nicht. Meinst du "das Durchfallen"?

Comment: Wenn die Abwesenheit von Abtönungspartikeln und Redensarten die Formalität eines Schreiben definiert, wer eine C1-Prüfung ablegen will, der sollte wohl schon die zu identifizieren gelernt haben. Für ein hohes Niveau würde ich das erwarten. Die sind aber in jedem nennenswerten Wörterbuch signalisiert, oder hast du eines gefunden, das das nicht tut?

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe keine direkte Antwort, aber ich hatte an einem deutschen Sprachinstitut ähnliche Erfahrungen. (Es wurde mir sogar gesagt, dass ich eher informell schreibe.) Meiner Meinung nach wäre es am besten, sich auf die Lernmaterialien statt auf das Wörterbuch zu fokussieren. Und mit dem meine ich vor allem Sachliteratur zu lesen. Man bekommt viel Kontext für Alltagswörter, die nicht immer deutlich definiert werden aber vom Kontext ganz einfach zu verstehen (und dadurch anwenden) sind. Das hilft besonders gut bei der Wortwahl.

Es hängt ja natürlich auch vom Verlag ab. Zum Beispiel kann eine Zeitung bestimmte Themen und Nachrichten ausgezeichnet erläutern, aber trotz der Qualität des Inhalts nicht ganz formell klingen. Allerdings ist man mit einer Mischung von Medien (Nachrichten und dann auch zusätzliche Sachliteratur) schon ziemlich gut vorbereitet.

Was ich auch im Nachhinein hilfreich finde, ist die deutsche Version einer Webseite zu lesen. Wenn ich beispielsweise einen englischen Eintrag (einer Enzyklopädie, einer Zeitung, usw.) finde, versuche ich ab und zu mal die deutsche Variante zu finden und zu lesen. Im Allgemeinen kann man die Wortwahl und den Ton des Textes mit dem Inhalt zusammenketten. Man kann dadurch einigermaßen ein Bauchgefühl entwickeln, ob was unangemessen ist.

Es gibt Lernmaterialien vom [Goethe-Institut](https://www.goethe.de/en/spr/kup/prf/prf/gc1/ueb.html), sowie die von [DW](https://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/level-c/s-13231). (Die DW-Artikel habe ich in der Schule irgendwann mal gesehen.)

Wenn ich mich nicht verkehrt bin darf man auch ein Wörterbuch mit zur Prüfung bringen. Dafür stimme ich den anderen Antworten völlig zu. Aber am Ende des Tages gibt es auch diejenigen, die super streng sind. Wen man als PrüferIn bekommt ist zufällig, und ob was ein bisschen oder sehr informell ist, kann auch subjektiv sein. Ich würde mir keine Sorgen darüber machen, ehrlich gesagt. Das muss ja auch nicht perfekt sein (vielleicht nur wenn man eine 1,0 will aber das ist eine andere Geschichte).

Viel Erfolg!!

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, die Antwort steht in den Kommentaren, ich formuliere es nochmal aus.

In praktisch allen Wörterbüchern, zum Beispiel dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de), sind Wörter, die für einen formalen Zusammenhang nicht geeignet sind, entsprechend gekennzeichnet. Dazu werden Beschreibungen des Wortes wie "salopp", "umgangsprachlich", "derb", "vulgär", "diskriminierend" oder "herabsetzend" benutzt, die das weiter differenzieren.

Wenn eine Prüferin in einem offiziellen Sprachtest einen Ausdruck bemängelt, muss sie das nachvollziehbar begründen können -- und das kann sie auch nur mit Hilfe solche Beschreibungen in den Wörterbüchern. Wenn das Wort ohne einen entspechenden Hinweis in den Wörterbüchern steht, kann dir das Wort nicht negativ angerechnet werden. Eine verlässlichere Quelle, auf die sich die Prüferin beziehen könnte, gibt es nicht.

Comment: Wie kann man einem Wörterbuch nur so viel Macht einräumen? (Insbesondere, wenn man bedenkt, wie grob dann die Unterscheidungen wären. Es gäbe eigentlich nur drei Ebenen: umgangssprachlich, neutral, gehoben. Da ist das Auge jedes sprachlich Geschulten um einiges feiner.)

Comment: Naja, beim Scrabble kann ich auch nicht sagen: mein Sprachgefühl als sprachlich Geschulter ist um einiges feiner als der Duden, und "Schwanzhund" ist ganz klar ein Wort.
Was ich sagen will, ist, dass es real halt nur eine Instanz gibt, die nicht der Prüfer selbst ist und die dem Schüler auch beim Lernen zugänglich ist, und das sind eben  Wörterbücher. Die Prüfung streng auf den Vokabelschatz der Prüfungen zu beschränken, wäre auch absurd.

Comment: LOL - Scrabble! (Musste neulich lernen, daß "MUHKUH" tatsächlich ein gültiges Wort ist!) ;)

Comment: Ich störe mich an dem Satz "Wenn das Wort ohne einen entspechenden Hinweis in den Wörterbüchern steht, kann dir das Wort nicht negativ angerechnet werden". Wörterbücher schreiben auch nicht alles immer 100% auf und sind fehlerbehaftet. Der Prüfer hat das Fachgebiet studiert. Seine Autorität kann nicht mit fehlenden Einträgen in Wörterbüchern untergraben werden.

Comment: Ich glaube, du überschätzt das Studium, aber das ist ein anderes Thema. Die Autorität des Prüfers steht dem Sprachschüler in der Lernphase nicht zur Verfügung. Ein Prüfer, der einen Ausdruck als zu umgangssprechlich anstreicht, und auch nach einem Hinweis darauf, dass in mehreren Wörterbüchern nichts von "umgangssprachlich" steht, darauf besteht, wird es im Zweifel von Gericht sehr schwer haben. Selbst wenn er recht hat, wäre es einfach sehr ungerecht, dem Schüler zum Vorwurf zu machen, dass er nicht mehr weiß als in den Wörterbüchern steht. Was ist denn Euer Vorschlag?