# Grammar/Sources recomendation

Tags: standard-german, learning

I have just joined this community and I really want to learn by my own German. On StackExchange English Language they have lots of grammar suggestions, however, I could not find a similar post here (searched for book recomendation, no results were found). So, I would like to know which grammars and other sources as well you guys recommend.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. You might try a search for resources: e.g. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german should pop up.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm There are zero grammars on that page. (Except one practice grammar.)

Comment: I would like to thank you!

Comment: @Mr.N: I see your "narrowed topic". While I saw more than one grammar link - I never had to learn German grammar through English, so I apologize for not checking on "usefulness"