# Advice on a suitable study plan

Tags: learning

I took a German B2 course a year ago. I would like to improve my German so I have been doing some translations. However, the difficulties with verbs that require dative or accusative forms and the usage of separable verbs, and so on, made me think that I need a proper study plan. Can anyone suggest a suitable intensive study plan for me? Any advice would be appreciated, I am feeling a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

Comment: hi, thanks for the link. However, I need a plan rather than a resources.

Comment: https://learngerman.dw.com/en/overview not really a "plan" but a nice resource

Answer (score 2):

There are several published study plans. One such is the series called *Aspekte*, published by *LektorKlett* and available from several online bookstores. There are various forms of the text that cover both teaching material and exercises (drills). The style of the books are such that a learner should be able to progress through the book from the beginning to end and cover all the material necessary for a particular level from B1 onwards. You should probably be looking for a combination "Lehrbuch + Arbeitsbuch".