# Where should I look for the plural of a word?

Tags: dictionary

I was looking for the plural of Heft (and still). My small Collins English/German/English doesn't have it. Where should I look for the plural of a German word?

Comment: Here: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/booklet

Comment: Have you looked at this [answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1696) and tried a few? My favourite is [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Heft), but your mileage may vary....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: I had already referred the *dictionaries* answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Try: https://www.duden.de https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heft_Schrift_Broschur

Duden is the standard dictionary in germany and it has also a good website with nearly every German word.

Comment: Well, it is true that the *Duden* dictionaries in book format are, or better: used to be, a standard reference in Germany. But the website *Duden Online* is certainly not. It often proves to be incomplete, imprecise, occasionally just plain wrong. Much better alternatives are *Wiktionary* (de.wiktionary.org) and, currently the most comprehensive dictionary, the *Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* (dwds.de).

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: I'd add that online Duden has so much spam that it nearly breaks my browser, so given that there are free and ad-free alternatives it's hard to see why it's not a last resort. Also, don't discount English Wiktionary; I don't know if its German coverage is as complete as the German version, but it has 99% of the words you might commonly encounter.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best resources for inflection of any German word is Wiktionary. For example here is the page for [Heft in Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Heft).

You can see, that there are two entries for two different nouns:

- Heft = booklet, notebook
- Heft = haft, handle

and for each of these words there is a full table with all inflected forms, which in the case of *Heft* is equal for both words.

---

If you search for a verb, like [gehen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gehen), you will find only the most important inflections on the main page, but each verb has a separate page where [all possible inflections](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:gehen) are listed.

Also all adjective have a main page (for example [schön](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sch%C3%B6n)) and an extra page for [all possible inflections](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sch%C3%B6n).

So, if you are searching for any inflection of any German word, you will find it on Wiktionary.