# Welcher Begriff bedeutet “to get someone in trouble”

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, phrase

Im Englischen kann der Ausdruck „to get someone in(to) trouble“ unterschiedliche Nebenbedeutungen haben. Er kann auch absichtlich oder unabsichtlich gemeint werden, je nach dem Kontext. Gibt es einen passenden deutschen Begriff, der einer oder mehreren Nebenbedeutungen entspricht?

Soweit habe ich nichts im Deutsch-Englischen Wörterbuch gefunden.

Comment: Du sagst nicht, welches Wörterbuch hier versagt hat. Es gibt bessere, auch online, siehe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/23).

Comment: Absichtlich oder nicht ist keine Nebenbedeutung, sondern eine möglicherweise fehlende Zusatzinformation. Wenn ich sage "Ich gehe am Samstag ins Kino" hat das auch nicht die Nebenbedeutung, dass ich je nach Kontext auch auswärts esse. Jmd. in Schwierigkeiten bringen beschreibt einen Sachverhalt - ob absichtlich oder nicht ist eine andere Frage. "Er hat die Vase kaputt gemacht." hat auch keine Konnotation, je nach Kontext, absichtlich oder unabsichtlich. Im Englischen ist es nicht anders.

Comment: @guidot In diesem Fall Linguee und dict.cc.

Comment: @userunknown Guter Punkt. Die einzigen Beispiele, die mir eingefallen sind, waren auch bloß von der Bedeutung abhängig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, ob ich die Frage recht verstanden habe und Sie nach *einer* allumfassenden Formulierung suchen, oder ob Sie nach *mehreren* Formulierungen mit je anderen Nebenbedeutungen suchen. Wie dem auch sei, es gibt im Deutschen verschiedene Formulierungen, die dem englischen *to get someone into trouble* entsprechen, zum Beispiel:

**mit *bringen***

- jmd. in Schwierigkeiten bringen
- jmd. in eine missliche Lage bringen
- jmd. in eine Zwickmühle bringen
- jmd. in die Bredouille bringen
- jmd. in Bedrängnis bringen
- jmd. in eine Notlage bringen
- jmd. in Verlegenheit bringen

**mit *bereiten***

- jmdm. Schwierigkeiten bereiten
- jmdm. Probleme bereiten
- jmdm. Ärger bereiten
- jmdm. Sorgen bereiten

**mit *setzen***

- jmd. in Verlegenheit setzen

---

Dies ist ein *Community wiki*. Wer mag, darf der Liste gern weitere Formulierungen hinzufügen.

Comment: Das wurde richtig verstanden - ich wollte halt jede Formulierung, die von diesem Begriff abgedeckt wäre. Danke!

Answer (score 5):

You would normally use "jemanden in Schwierigkeiten bringen", which can be both, intentional or (I think more often) unintentional. When you do it on purpose, you could say "jemandem Schwierigkeiten bereiten" or "Jemandem Ärger einbringen (could also be unintentional) / machen (you are the trouble yourself).

There might be some other translations as well, but I'd need more context for them.

Comment: It's normally translated like this but it's useful to look at the alternatives