# Leicht zu verwechselnde Wörter

Tags: adjective-ending

In meinem Online-Deutschkurs habe ich die folgenden Übungen gemacht:

**Wähle das passende Adjektiv aus.**

> *ehrlich/ehrenvoll*
>
> Ich habe die xxx Aufgabe, die Lobrede zu halten.
> Sei xxx zu mir: Sehe ich in diesem Kleid zu dick aus?

oder noch:

> *sparsam/spärlich*
>
> Auch ein sehr xxx Mensch kann von diesem  xxx Einkommen nicht leben.

Und es gibt noch einige weitere Beispiele: *folgsam/folglich/folgend; kostbar/köstlich, ....*

Aber leider gab es keine Erklärung in dieser Übung.
Meine Frage:
Gibt es eine Technik, um zu wissen, wann man welches Adjektiv verwendet/auswählt?

(Oder ist das einfach nur Vokabular?)

Comment: Ja, das ist "nur" Vokabular. Ohne ein gutes Wörterbuch funktioniert das Lernen nicht, einige Vorschläge sind in [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1696) zusammengetragen. *Folgsam* und *folglich* sind komplett unterschiedliche Wörter, und haben die unterschiedlichen Wortarten Adjektiv und Konjunktion.

Comment: Manch ein Test ist in dem Sinne anstrpuchsvoll, dass der das überpfüft, was man schon lange her gemacht hat (m.E. hilft hier einem am meisten, schon in der Vergangenheit gelesen zu haben--angenommen, WB-Nachchlagen ist nicht gestattet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist größtenteils Vokabular.

Deine Beispiele  -lich, -bar, -voll und -sam sind sehr frühe, teilweise noch auf germanische Wortildungssuffixe zurückzuführende (vgl. z.B. "-lich" mit dem englischen "-ly" oder "-voll" und "-ful[l]") Produktionssuffixe. Die abgeleiteten Wörter hatten also sehr viel Zeit, sich in der täglichen Sprachpraxis von ihrer ursprünglichen Ableitungsbedeutung zu entfernen oder sich zu spezialisieren und können damit sehr leicht auch "falsche Freunde" werden. Bisweilen existiert heute nur noch die Ableitung, das ursprüngliche Stammwort ist aber verlorengegangen (z.B. im Fall des Adjektivs "urbar"). Das zunächst mal als Warnung.

Eine Eselsbrücke kann die Zurückführung auf einen Wortstamm aber trotzdem sein:

"*-lich*" kann Adjektive u.a. aus Substantiven, Verben und Adjektiven bilden. Das hilft uns leider nicht viel weiter, die mögliche Bandreite ist einfach viel zu groß. Hier hilft fast immer nur das Wörterbuch.

"*-bar*" liefert fast immer ein Adjektiv aus einem Verb, und bedeutet dann etwas im Sinne von "geeignet, zu xxx" oder "geeignet, xxx zu werden" (z.B. "brenn*bar*" = "geeignet, verbrannt zu werden" oder "geeignet, zu brennen"). Damit kann man die möglichen Bedeutungen schon stark einschränken

"*-voll*" liefert fast immer ein Adjektiv aus einem Substantiv, die Ableitung ist sehr direkt und bedeutet "voll von ..." ("wundervoll" == "voll von Wundern")

"*-sam*" liefert ein Adjektiv aus einem Verb oder Substantiv und wird größtenteils verwendet, um Charaktereigenschaften, Neigungen oder Fähigkeiten von hauptsächlich Personen oder "erfüllt sein von", wenn es von einem Substantiv ableitet, zu beschreiben. Hier kann es wieder Mißverständnisse geben, wenn man die falsche Herkunft annimmt ("*wundersam" z.B. heißt nicht etwa "fähig, sich zu wundern", sondern "erfüllt von Wundern". Hier hilft also wieder nur das Wörterbuch.

Nehmen wir mal Produkte mit "Wunder" bzw. "sich wundern" (weil das so schön mit allen Produktionssuffixen funktioniert):

**wunderlich** - "merkwürdig, seltsam", - "man wundert sich darüber", funktioniert nur mit Personen - "Meine Nachbarin ist wunderlich - sie spricht mit ihrem Kaktus"

**wunderbar** - "wie ein Wunder" - unerwartet, ungewöhnlich, im übertragenen Sinne auch "schön" ("wunderbares Wetter heute!")

**wundervoll** - "voll von Wundern" - Synonym zum Vorigen

**wundersam** - "seltsam", "geheimnisvoll", "eigenartig", wird, im Gegensatz zu "wunderlich" eher für Vorgänge als Personen benutzt. "auf wundersame Weise verschwand mein Portemonnaie"