# Is there service where i can read and listen to the book at the same time?

Tags: translation, learning

Is there any mobile apps or online service where you can read, listen to german books and make some notes or even translation (at least to select the word).

I know the similar services by famous brand. But you have to buy every single book there in spite of you have monthly subscription. I'm looking for service where is only monthly pay and no limit for book reading/listening. And all i found has only audio and no text or vice versa.

Is there smth like that?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. So you found a service that fulfills all your needs and is just book based instead of a monthly fee? Because asking for a functionality is something different then asking for a business model. Taking notes is what some PDF readers offer - just there is no audio book included. So you would have to buy both. Despite that, there is a thread about learning ressources: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Answer (score 2):

As for monthly pay, that I'm not aware of. Have you considered buying books which have audio included/you can download so you pay once and it's yours for good?

What the topic is depends on your level of German.

There are these A1 books in the "Stadt, Land, Fluss" series (for youth, however they are great for German beginners and people in the first few stages of German learning).

I recommend them *all the time*. They have text and audio - physical or digital: [https://www.amazon.com/Schatz-von-Hiddensee-eingebettetem-Audio-File-ebook/dp/B00Z6KEZTQ/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00Z6KEZTQ)

You buy them once and they're yours. If you buy the physical copy you can download the accompanying MP3s once and listen to them as much as you want.

Does that help at least a bit? If you need something at a different level I might know of it already. Happy to help!