# What’s the best way to actually test yourself in German?

Tags: standard-german, proficiency-test

I am currently learning German and have a friend from Morocco who understands a little. Most of the time when I have a conversation in German people seem to understand what I’m trying to say. But I can’t help but wonder what my actual level of understanding is or my progress is. What in your opinion is the best way to test your skills and maybe learn from your mistakes while doing so?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic for the site since it's not so much about the German language as language learning in general. The [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate spot for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The Goethe institute offers official tests which certify you whatever level of German you test for:

https://www.goethe.de/ins/de/en/prf.html

They also offer a guide and an [online test](https://www.goethe.de/ins/de/en/prf/tsd.html) on how to judge which of the levels your skill corresponds to and thus which tests is the most appropriate one for you.

If you are looking for a less formal way: [read books and watch TV / video](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/36160). Don't start with Kant or Nietzsche, but with simpler works, maybe targetting children (what about Sendung mit der Maus? I find it interesting as adult, too).

Comment: Kant or Nietzsche? What are you talking about? What has the language of Kant in common with the language of Nietzsche? Kant has nothing to do with modern German while Nietzsche is almost the core of modern German. Watch TV/Video? Yeah, because they speak totally natural German language - especially in movies!
Goethe-Institute is a good hint and I really like your advice to watch "Sendung mit der Maus".

Comment: ok danke für den Rat. It is greatly appreciated.