# German by natural approach

Tags: learning, book

I want to learn German using the [direct method/natural approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_approach). I'm looking for the book similar to Latin *Lingua Latina per se illustrata* by [Hans Orberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_%C3%98rberg), where you basically learn Latin using the target language, not a single word is written in any other language. Do you know if there's the similar book for German? If not what workbook do you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do I understand you correct that you want a "learn German" book that treats you as a German native speaker? And as an adult? (Sorry, don't speak latin, so I can't judge your example). While the method is called also "Natural Approach" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_approach), I have the feeling that any "good" book "Deutsch für Ausländer" might come close.

Comment: I am not sure, if a book request is on-topic here.

Comment: We have a [list of resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german) you may want to peruse.

Answer (score 2):

Using parameters similar to those outlined, may I recommend the multi-modal package 'Deutsch mit Schmidt' on Audible Books.

My background as a Linguist can identify several Second Language Methodologies the author has identified with, and the programme is created around CEFL Learning milestones A1, A2, B1, B2, C1 and C2.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please consider integrating your answer into the list of answers linked by RDBury: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Answer (score 2):

[Deutsch nach der Naturmethode](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf8XN5kNFkhc0J7rC_vQMUBIVdaj---V5) is the equivalent of LLPSI of Hans O. and English by the Nature Method, L'italiano secondo il metodo natura, etc. of Arthur Jensen.