# Best reference book for German grammar?

Tags: book

I need to get to know the basic grammar of the German language in a short period of time. I previously used Bennet's *New Latin Grammar* to study Latin and I found it to be quite helpful since it was both comprehensive and plain at the same time.

Please suggest one such academic reference book for studying German.

Comment: Especially [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24955/1696) answer to Davids linked question may give a starting point.

Comment: Asking for the **best** is likely to be considered as opinion-based. I recommend to replace *academic*  by more description of your expectations.