# Youtube videos for intermediate-level learners?

Tags: online-resource

I'm looking for German Youtube channels/videos to watch that are good for advanced beginner-lower intermediate speakers to get more exposure to the language.  That is, content that is entirely (or almost entirely) in German, but still targeted towards language learners.  In other words, something between the two extremes of beginner videos with a lot of English, and "normal" Youtube content targeted towards native speakers.

Some very excellent examples (for other languages) are [Nihongo no Mori](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVx6RFaEAg46xfAsD2zz16w) and [Sambon Juku](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0ujXryUUwILURRKt9Eh7Nw) for Japanese, and [Hola Spanish](https://www.youtube.com/c/HolaSpanish) and [Spanish after hours](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfG2VhlQgy5bHGmkpeKcjVA/featured) for Spanish.

[Easy German](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbxb2fqe9oNgglAoYqsYOtQ) is great (as are all the other "easy languages" channels!) but two small complaints I have are that (1) they include English subitles on everything, and (2) much of their content is street interviews, so the level can vary a lot.

Comment: Maybe this fits. https://youtube.com/c/Deutschplus it is mostly short videos on a specific and sometimes subtle topic

Comment: This site has a [FAQ on learning resources](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/43989) which might help. The answer labelled "Video resources" should be a good starting point.

Comment: @planetmaker That is indeed a good one, thanks!  You should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: @RDBury Yes, there is indeed a "video resources" section on that page, but that hasn't been updated much recently and didn't contain many examples of the kind I was looking for.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Yes, it is somewhat similar to an existing question, but it asks a well defined specific question (requesting resources of a *specific* type) and may well be useful to others as well as me (the OP).  The desired information is not well covered on the FAQ page, and as @planetmaker's comment above shows, there *is* useful information to be gained from this question.

Comment: I updated the "video resources" section late last year with two new links, and I just added another link, so it now has all the resources I know about at this point. I guess I'm still unclear on exactly what you're looking for. Easy German is already on the list and I'm not familiar with the Japanese and Spanish channels you listed. I do subscribe to a few more German learning channels, but those are more instructional (grammar, vocabulary, etc), not mainly for listening practice.

Comment: Perhaps part of the problem is that most of regulars here are native speakers and not actively learning German as a new language. They wouldn't know good resources for learning German any more than I would know good resources for learning English. I learned about quite a few learning resources when I was on DuoLingo since it has its own discussion areas, so you might do better with something like that. I admit I don't do as much listening practice as I should, but when I do I mainly listen to pop music (*Schlager*) and watch video game Let's Plays.

Comment: @RDBury Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I'm complaining about the fact that *this question was closed*.  Yes, there is overlap with the FAQ, but it asks a *specific, well defined, potentially useful* question.  If later *someone else* comes across this question and knows of examples of the kind requested, they would post it here, whereas they may not have done so had they merely come across the FAQ page.   In that respect, this is question is *useful* as it potentially helps add to the knowledge collected on this site.

Comment: Of course, this culture of strongly opposing and aggressively closing any questions that be even remotely close to a "duplicate" is common across stackexchange, not just the German language stackexchange.  It is something that I personally find strange and illogical, but of course there are many who disagree with me.