# about finding a proper German language learning app with low interactive educational methods

Tags: learning

I am an electrical engineer and, because of some conditions, work as a house cleaner ( maid).

I am trying to learn German to qualify myself for a German job speaker visa, and I am searching for some android German language learning app which I could use during my 4 or 8 hours' time of house cleaning.

I can not communicate with that app and, in this situation, I think it must be an application which learns German in one direction and doesn't ask questions from me. I guess playing a educational video podcast or ... Would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Unidirectional learning will not be good way to learn anything. While it might make good use of your time during cleaning, you should definitely try something interactive in between.

Comment: Do you plan to organize your studies during the week and dedicate time for that or you will only have those hours available? You might have different audio only strategies depending on how you organize yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a podcast type course, then Deutsche Welle (DW) has a few entertaining options to get you started, all for free. Check the [Audio Resources](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9532/43989) answer in the FAQ mentioned in the comments above. But, as also mentioned in the comments, an audio course won't get you to a certification and you really need some kind of interactive study if you're at all serious. While this site can answer specific questions about the German language, we don't generally offer advice on language courses. First, because such advice would be opinion based, and also because you can probably get more detailed results from a search engine and independent reviews. Keep in mind that most of the regulars here speak German as their first language, so they don't have a lot of experience trying to learn German as a foreign language.