# A1, A2 and B1 revision

Tags: low-german

I passed my B1 in 2020 after that I lost touch with the language. I can understand German well but I want to revise my grammar and vocabulary.

Can anyone suggest me some good books and online resources for that?

Comment: This site maintains a [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/43989) FAQ for such questions.

Comment: @RDBury Thank you

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:low-german]? Are you trying to learn Low German? That would be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit the Studio d Books. The end of each chapter recaps everything done in chapter, mainly the Grammar.

You can visit these pages to quickly revise everything so far.

The last pages of the books also has all the verbs and vocabulary for that level.