# Do you know any platform where I could find lectures in German?

Tags: resource, online-resource

I have been struggling to find academic lectures in German - something similar to what you would find on [MIT Open Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/search/), [edX](https://www.edx.org/), or even on Youtube (it could be a channel or a playlist wherein I could find lectures whose format would be something like this one: [Schopenhauer: The World as Will and Idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-Ij9EvjFeU&list=PLGCHvDjfDoxIlYZma9T1vHrsIJKepf4lw&index=13) - similar to old lectures from [The Great Courses](https://The%20Great%20Courses) *in case you are familiar with it.* It could also be a channel or a playlist with formal interviews with academics, writers, intellectuals like this one: ["The Dumbest Generation"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHTqQWCAgtE) - or any type that would *not* verge on *infotainment*. Such lectures or interviews could be about a variety of subjects from Ancient History to Neuroanatomy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resources in general are collected in [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/1696).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a bit offtopic because it's not really about the German language, and it's also very broad, but let's view this as a question for German material on a higher language level.

There's a plethora of academic lectures and talks on Youtube, just search for the topic you're interested in *in German* with the word "Vorlesung" or "Vortrag", for example "Vorlesung Philosophie" will yield several different playlists of introductory philosophy courses, same for Physics with "Vorlesung Physik".

For example, I enjoyed [a series of 60 minutes talks on great thinkers](https://www.youtube.com/@dr.waltherziegler2523) by Dr. Walther Ziegler.

More advanced lectures might be harder to find because professors have less ambition to upload them for later reference.

For professional training, there are offerings like [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) etc. that offer courses in German. If you're trying to get an academic degree online, there's the "Fernunis" (remote universities), most notably [Fernuni Hagen](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/).

The audience a creator is able to reach with a German lecture will never be comparable to what they can reach with an English lecture, so for advanced topics e.g. in STEM, you will probably be better off looking for English resources. Even some German universities are likely to record advanced lectures in English. I don't think that there is anything comparable to MIT's complete online course program in German.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: A good search term (e.g. on YouTube) is also "Ringvorlesung" - a term which finds nearly exclusively lectures targeting the general public with a talk usually on the lecturer's research subject.