# Android app for verb and case

Tags: grammatical-case

I am fairly fluent in German (B2 with "Sehr Gut" and a few C1 conversation courses) but I still sometimes struggle deciding whether to use the dative or accusative case. Could someone recomment an app I could just use whenever I get a spare minute or so to practice verbs and cases. I often used the app "King of German Article" to practise gender and it really helped me a lot, I would like something similar for verbs and case.

Comment: For example the Verbformen app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.verbformen.verben.app

Comment: I admit, that [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9531/1696) resources answer is a bit thin on apps, but for Android the search terms *Deutsch* and *Verben* produces some decent rated stuff.