# Advanced German videos at C1-C2 level

Tags: german-to-english, resource

All the resources I see on the internet seem to be mostly focused on till intermediate level (B1-B2). I have found this [nice channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAeKKAuqrh4) for C1-C2, but further resources I can't. Could someone recommend me some good resources? Thanks.

Comment: What about the EasyGerman youtube channel?

Comment: Find it too basic at thsi point@Janka

Comment: "nice channel" is not a name :)

Comment: Are you looking for instructional videos like the one you linked to, or anything in German at the C1 and C2 level?

Comment: anything p.m. @Raketenolli

Comment: We have an FAQ for learning resources: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german. If you're just looking to practice your skills then I'd think at C level you could just watch German language television or videos; what to watch is up to your individual taste.

Answer (score 2):

**Youtube Channels for C1-C2 Level**

- [Deutsch mit Marija](https://www.youtube.com/@DeutschmitMarija)
- [Deutsch mit Rieke](https://www.youtube.com/@deutschmitrieke)
- [Deutsch mit Benjamin](https://www.youtube.com/@DeutschMitBenjamin)
- [Benjamin - Der Deutschlehrer](https://www.youtube.com/@BenjaminDerDeutschlehrer)
- [Deutsch Plus](https://www.youtube.com/@Deutschplus)
- [Deutsch Lera](https://www.youtube.com/@DeutschLera)

**Books by SCHUBERT VERLAG** ([main website](https://www.schubert-verlag.de))

- Erkundungen B2, Erkundungen C1, Erkundungen C2 - [Product Page](https://www.schubert-verlag.de/erkundungen_info.php)
- C-Grammatik - [Product Page](https://www.schubert-verlag.de/abc-grammatik.php)

**Books for Exam Preparation**

- Endstation C2 for Goethe Zertifikat C2
- Mit Erfolg zum Goethe-Zertifikat C1
- Mit Erfolg zum Goethe-Zertifikat C2: GDS
- Fit furs Goethe-Zertifikat: C1
- Mittelpunkt Neu B2 and Mittelpunkt Neu C1

**For Improving Hearing and Speaking**

- *NEWS Channels:* Tagesschau, NDR, WDR, DW Deutsch
- *Documentaries (in Youtube):* Terra X, NDR Doku, WDR Doku, ARTEde
- *Science and Technology:* [Quarks.de](https://www.quarks.de/)