# Können als Helvetismus?

Tags: swiss-german

Guten Abend

Ich bin Finne und ich mag Helvetismen.

In meinen Helvetismen-Notizen gibt es eine Markierung über dem Wort „mögen“, aber ich konnte das nicht weder finden noch durch Duden oder DWDS konfirmieren.

Könnte jemand erklären, welche besondere Bedeutung „mögen“ in der Schweiz haben könnte?

Comment: Was jetzt? "können" (Überschrift) oder "mögen" (Text)?

Answer (score 4):

Für Fragen nach schweizerischem Deutsch gibt es das "Schweizer Idiotikon":
https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id4.htm#!page/40107/mode/1up
(Das Wort "Idiotikon" bezieht sich ürigens auf "Eigenheiten", gelehrte Entlehnung aus dem Griechischen, auch wenn normale Leute hier grinsen).

Dort stehen (Band 4, Spalte 107ff., wie verlinkt) so Sachen wie "mögen" als "gesund / kräftig" sein: "I mag nümme" (ich mag nimmer) = "Ich bin nicht gesund, bin erschöpft." Auch "jemand möge" = jemanden übertreffen ("dr hätt a dr Abstimmig möge" = er hat bei der Abstimmung gewonnen). Abgesehen von dem Sinn "wollen, Appetit haben", den man als Deutscher schon eher versteht.

Man muss bei dem Werk nur aufpassen, dass auch sehr alte Belege gebracht werden (wie beim Grimm'schen Wörterbuch).

Comment: This is a link-only answer and should be amended by the important facts so that it can stand without the link.

Comment: This is because it is a question that can be resolved by looking up in a dictionary.

Comment: Then it is off-topic and a close-reason.

Comment: but not before you know where to find the dictionary :) Let's not be too formalistic

Comment: [Link-only answers are not ok across the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/310311) and have been for a decade, the reasons are outlined in the meta post linked here. So if you could find the energy to include the relevant information _in the post_ (properly attributed, of course), you’d get upvotes instead of comments and flags.

Comment: I added the Idiotikon to the resources page: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9535/1696

Comment: More links, very good.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort und Hilfe.

Comment: Man wird in den deutschsprachigen mathematischen Zeitschriften des (vor)letzten Jahrhunderts häufig den Satzanfang
"Vermögens Gleichung xx" finden, was sich nicht auf pekuniäres bezieht sondern bedeutet, daß die Gültigkeit der Gleichung es erlaubt/ermőglicht wie folgt fortzufahren.

Answer (score 1):

Das Verb *mögen* wird generell in den südlichen Dialekten gern anstelle von *können* verwendet, wenn man ein Mittelding zwischen *können* und *wollen* meint.

Das ist nicht speziell schweizerisch.

Comment: Okay. Ich raffe es. 