# Obligatorisches "es" bei Passivkonstruktionen

Tags: passive

Nach [dieser Webseite](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/passiv/passiv-umformung-es/)

(1)

> In Passivkonstruktionen kann in Position 1 *es* stehen. Wenn der
> Aktivsatz nur aus einem unpersönlichen Nominativ (man) und einem Verb
> besteht, ist *es* im Passivsatz als Nominativersatz obligatorisch.

Und

(2)

> In allen anderen Sätzen kann man auch eine andere Ergänzung in
> Position 1 stellen, dann ist *es* überflüssig, stilistisch schlecht und
> sollte wegfallen.

Dennoch

(3)

> Trotzdem kann es Gründe geben *es* zu benutzen. Dann gilt Folgendes:
> Wenn der Aktivsatz einen Akkusativ enthält, hat der Passivsatz einen
> Nominativ. Die Verbform richtet sich dann nach dem Nominativ.

Was wären dann diese Gründe, *es* zu benutzen? Mir scheint es, dass (2) und (3) sich wiedersprechen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Man übt. → Es wird geübt.

Aber:

- Man übt Geige. → Geige wird geübt.

Nun ist *Geige* aber Thema des Satzes geworden, wo zuvor noch der Platzhalter *man* das Thema war. Das ist meistens nicht so gewollt, der passende Aktivsatz dazu lautet eher:

- Geige übt man. → Geige wird geübt.

Hier bleibt *Geige* das Thema. Das passt.

Alternativ daher:

- Man übt Geige. → Geübt wird Geige.

Oder eben:

- Man übt Geige. → Es wird Geige geübt.

Diese letzte Form ist viel üblicher, wenn das Verb allein ziemlich aussagelos ist. Der Sinn liegt darin, dass im letzten Satz diese doch sehr spezielle Tätigkeit *Geige üben* weiterhin eng beisammen steht. Du wirst sogar eher

- Man übt Geige. → Geige geübt wird.

finden, als das *Geige* allein zum Thema des Satzes erhoben wird.

Comment: +1, aber die Behauptung im letzten Satz, "Geige geübt wird." würde man eher finden als "Geige wird geübt", geht mir dann doch zu weit.

Answer (score 3):

Solche Seiten sind suchmaschinenoptimierter Mist, um Traffic zu generieren.

(1) ist falsch: Wenn *es* ein Nominativersatz wäre, müßte es auch im Nebensatz stehen können.

> wenn (*es) gearbeitet wird

Die Seite suggeriert zu Unrecht, daß *es* irgendetwas mit Passiv zu tun hätte. Beispiele im Aktiv mit einem Subjekt im Plural:

> Es sollten endlich Taten folgen.
> Es könnten auch andere Faktoren eine Rolle spielen.
> Es werden sicherlich viele Leute von außerhalb kommen.

Diese Beispiele widersprechen (2).

Comment: Könntest du Online-Quellen für Antworten auf solche Fragen empfehlen?

Comment: Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9560, unter "German grammar".

Comment: Dagegen man im Passiv: man wird hier oft geholfen (oder "da werden sie geholfen", Verona Feldbusch)

Comment: Na ja, das war ja absichtlich falsches Deutsch, ist also kaum als Referenz geeignet.

Answer (score 0):

Ich benutze die Beispiele von Janka.

*Man übt Geige* würde ich verwenden, wenn ich eine allgemeingültige Aussage machen möchte. Der Satz kann dann etwa folgende Bedeutungen haben: "Wenn man schon etwas sinnvolles im Leben tun möchte, dann übt man Geige" oder "Geige muss man üben, sonst lernt man es nicht".

> Kinder aus oberen Gesellschaftschichten spielen nicht E-Gitarre oder gehen in den Fussballverein. Man übt Geige, reitet oder spielt Golf, wie es dem sozialen Stand entspricht.

> Man übt Geige ein Leben lang.

*Es wird Geige geübt* würde ich verwenden, wenn ich feststellen möchte, dass jemand Geige übt (aber nicht weiß oder nicht sagen möchte, wer): "Jemand übt Geige", oder wenn ich jemandem befehle, Geige zu üben: "Du übst jetzt Geige!".

Beispiele:

> In der Nachbarschaft lernen viele Kinder ein Instument. Es wird Geige geübt, Klarinette gespielt, gesungen und getrommelt.

> "Mama, ich möchte heute nicht Geige üben."
> "Es wird Geige geübt, und damit basta!"