# German dictionary program

Tags: learning, resource, software

I am looking for a German dictionary program that I can install on my Mac.  I would like the program to have:

- Definition of the word in English
- Audio files of the German pronunciation
- Declensions

I would prefer an actual program on my Mac because of the ease of use as well as I study frequently without a wifi connection.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/is-there-a-german-english-dictionary-in-pdf-or-that-works-offline, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/german-dictionary-with-detailed-declensions-audio-pronunciations-and-ipa

Comment: You could add [dict.cc](http://lipflip.org/articles/dictcc-dictionary-plugin) or [Beo Lingus](http://tekl.de/deutsch/BeoLingus_Deutsch-Englisch.html) to the built-in dictionary.app, although these don’t meet all your requirements (esp. audio) – so not an answer. If you want to convert a dictionary in Stardict format, e.g. [Wiktionary](http://www.dictinfo.com), you’ll need [Dict Unifier](https://github.com/jjgod/mac-dictionary-kit).

Comment: @Crissov said it all... get dict.cc into your Dictionary.app (and also offline on your phone). I would warn you that you need to be very apt with computers to get Wiktionary working offline. Some languages have been made available, but not many!

Answer (score 1):

German-English Collins Pro Dictionary

just run a quick Search. They do have a special Mac Version and last time I checked it was offered as a download.